# Sveltekit POST method not allowed on endpoint

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, endpoint, vite, sveltekit

I am trying to get this fetch method to work in Svelte

When the page.svelte calls the function to fetch the data, in the console I receive this

```
[HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed 19ms]
```

Which I have narrowed down to this

```
POST method not allowed
```

Is there a variable I need to set in the config files or is there another solution which I am missing?

// svelte.config.js

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';

const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
        methodOverride: {
            allowed: ['POST']
        },
    }
};

export default config;
```

Both files are in the Routes folder

// fetch-data.js

```
export const POST = async(data) => {
  const response = // get data function here
  return {
    body: {
        data: response
    }
  }
}
```

// page.svelte

```
async function fetchData() {
   const response = await fetch('./fetch-data', {
     method: 'POST',
     body: JSON.stringify(),
     headers: {
       'content-type': 'application/json'
     }
   })
   const { data } = await response.json()
   return data
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error for a different reason, and the syntax in your question and answer has changed again so I'll add my discoveries:

- `+page.server.ts` should no longer `export const POST` but instead `export const actions: Actions = { ... }` which don't need to return anything.
- `+server.ts` still uses `function POST(event: RequestEvent)` and needs to return a `Response` (from the Fetch API).
- Cookies can no longer be set with `setHeaders` but must use `cookies` instead. Otherwise the handler also returns 405.

Answer (score 3):

The solution was to change the `POST` variable name to lowercase in the get-data.js file

Comment: if you mean the line `export const POST`, you should update your SvelteKit, this has been changed recently to use uppercase

Comment: @StephaneVanraes ah thank you, I must’ve been using a previously made version that didn’t have that!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because of old SvelteKit version (I used .456, current version at the time this was written is .484). So make sure you have the most recent version of framework, when referring to the docs ;)